# UIImageView resizing Issue

Tags: ios

I am trying to add a horizontal overlay black bar to all the boxes I have. The boxes are sized in IB and their sizes are 328 X 300, at least that is why the interface builder says in the properties.

When I size my overlay image and size it to 328 width then it does not cover the complete view. The screenshot below shows what I am talking about:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
 thumbnailImageView = CGRectMake(0, 0, TILE_WIDTH,TILE_HEIGHT); // 328X300

UIView *blackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, thumbnailImageView.frame.size.height - 100, thumbnailImageView.bounds.size.width, thumbnailImageView.bounds.size.height/4)];
[thumbnailImageView addSubview:blackView];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use `thumbnailImageView.frame` instead of `thumbnailImageView.bounds`

```
UIView *blackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, thumbnailImageView.frame.size.height - 100, thumbnailImageView.frame.size.width, thumbnailImageView.bounds.size.height/4)]
```

Comment: But apart from the origin values the width and the height of frame and bounds are exactly the same all the time.

Comment: did u try to implement content mode ? or send your sample code to ramshadram90@gmail.com ..

Comment: content mode?? what is that and for that?

Comment: for the image view ? I have few more questions.. did u have black boarder for UIImageView ?  the black UIView representing the overlay image ?  black UIView width is ur problem right ?